# layoutConfig dosn't work in accordion layout in extjs 4

Tags: layout, extjs4, accordion, fill

I want to use viewport and use accordion layout for my menu items.
but I want my accordion layout not fill and use all spaces for each item
I use layoutConfig like examples but it dosn't work and the accordion fill all spaces and stretch vertically :

```
this.view = new Ext.Viewport({
layout: 'border',
renderTo : document.body,
items: [{
    xtype: 'box',
            region: 'north',
            height: 60,
            contentEl: 'framework_north'
        },{
            region: 'east',
            title: 'امکانات سیستم',
            split: true,
    collapsible: true,
            width: 200,
    minSize: 200,
            maxSize: 200,
    layout:'accordion',
    layoutConfig: {
        fill : false,
        collapseFirst : true,
        hideCollapseTool : true
    },
    tbar : [
    {
        contentEl : "framework_clock",
        autoWidth : true,
        xtype: 'box',
        height : 80
    }],
    items: this.menuItems
},
this.centerPanel]
```

});

what is my fault :'(

Answer (score 0):

wrap your accordion in a vbox container and set the height to whatever you want.